# XSLT 2 multiple file output

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I'm using saxon for xml to html transform with xslt and I need to have two output files one is the basic html and one is javascript file which can be text file if js is not supported.
here is my c# code for transform and part of xsl document. I need to have to outputs one html file from converted xml and one javascript file with some scripts

```
   public void ConvertXMLtoHTMLXSLT2Saxon()
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        string parentDirectory = myDirectory.Parent.Parent.FullName;
        string xsltFile = Path.Combine(parentDirectory, "test.xslt");
        string xmlFile = Path.Combine(myDirectory.FullName, "test.xml");

        // Create a Processor instance.
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        // Load the source document.
        XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(new Uri(xmlFile));

        // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
        XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(xsltFile)).Load();

        // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node.
        transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

        // BaseOutputUri is only necessary for xsl:result-document.
        transformer.BaseOutputUri = new Uri(xsltFile);

        // Create a serializer.
        Serializer serializer = new Serializer();

        serializer.SetOutputFile("test.html");

        // Transform the source XML to System.out.
        transformer.Run(serializer);
    }
```

and here the part of xsl document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script src="Scripts/test.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
 </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Page"> 
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:result-document href="{@Name}.js">
$(document).ready(function (){
--some javascript code--
})
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the secondary output document to be a plain text file then use e.g.

```
<xsl:result-document href="{@Name}.js" method="text">
$(document).ready(function (){
--some javascript code--
})
  </xsl:result-document>
```

XSLT has no special serialization for Javascript files so `method="text"` is the appropriate method.

Comment: Thank you its working the method="text" not needed without that its creating js file